# Bug with power-of-two multiplication in GBDK compiler

Tags: assembly, emulation, z80, gameboy, gbdk

I'm currently developing a gameboy emulator and to test the correctness of my emulator I'm using GBDK to compile c programs for my emulator.

I noticed that the compiler (as expected) optimizes multiplications with constants that are a power of two by doing rotates. However it appears that it does not generate the correct amount of rotates for a given power.

For example the following very simple program:

```
#include <gb/gb.h>

unsigned char one() { return 1; }

void main()
{
    unsigned char r;

    // Force compiler to generate muliplication by deferring the '1'
    r = one() * 32;

    // Store result somewhere
    *((unsigned char*)(0xFFFE)) = r;
}
```

Generates the following assembly:

```
___main_start:
_main:
    push    bc
;   reproduce.c 14
; genCall
    call    _one
    ld  c,e
; genLeftShift
    ld  a,c
    rr  a
    rr  a
    rr  a
    and a,#0xE0
    ld  c,a
;   reproduce.c 16
; genAssign
    ld  de,#0xFFFE
; genAssign (pointer)
    ld  a,c
    ld  (de),a
; genLabel
00101$:
; genEndFunction
    pop bc
    ret
___main_end:
    .area _CODE
```

Which to me appears to be incorrect as the RR instruction actually rotates through the carry flag, effectively making it a 9-bit rotate. This means that there should be an additional rotate to produce the correct result instead of the current (0x40) wrong result.

Visualization:

```
Start: A = 00000001 Carry = 0
RR A:  A = 00000000 Carry = 1
RR A:  A = 10000000 Carry = 0
RR A:  A = 01000000 Carry = 0 <- WRONG!
```

Can anyone verify that this is indeed a bug in the SDCC compiler that comes with GBDK? I'm also interested in the use of the and instruction following the rotates.

Using the latest (3-2.93) version of GBDK for windows from sourceforge.

Comment: The version of SDCC that comes with GBDK appears to be 2.2.1, which is something like 15 years old. The latest stable release of SDCC is 3.4.0, which is from April of 2014. Do you get the same generated code if you update your SDCC version?

Comment: I believe that the SDCC that comes with GBDK is a fork that's modified to produce gb compatible z80 code (at least the source code of sdcc is included in the gbdk source). But yeah, GBDK is ancient, but I would think that something as common as this would work.

Comment: Perhaps the SDCC master project didn't have GB-Z80 support at that time. But I believe it does now. I agree that it seems like a common scenario. OTOH, SDCC obviously doesn't have as many developer resources as e.g. GCC or LLVM. I've run into weird bugs in SDCC's Z80 compiler in the past, like having to replace `memcpy` with loops for the copy to work properly.

Comment: Ah, I see! I'll experiment with the latest sdcc later then. Thanks!

Comment: Just tried with the latest SDCC and it worked brilliant! Gonna try to recompile the GBDK libraries at which point I can ditch GBDK entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug with your emulator -- other emulators I've tested also give `64` for the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char one() { return 1; }

void main()
{
    unsigned int r;

    // Force compiler to generate multiplication by deferring the '1'
    r = one() * 32;

    printf("1 * 32 = %u", r);
}
```

Here it is on [BGB](http://bgb.bircd.org/) <sup>(version 1.5.1)</sup>:

[image: BGB version 1.5.1: 1 * 32 = 64]

And this is on [VBA-M](http://vba-m.com/) <sup>(version SVN1149)</sup>:

[image: VBA-M version SVN1149: 1 * 32 = 64]

---

As for why the `and a,#0xE0` is included?  That's actually simple.  It just ensures that overflow doesn't mess up the value.

First off, suppose that multiplication actually worked right, and 1 * 32 still equals 32.  (I'll just add an extra `RR A`).

For 1 * 32, this looks like this:

```
Start       ; A = 00000001 Carry = 0
RR  A       ; A = 00000000 Carry = 1
RR  A       ; A = 10000000 Carry = 0
RR  A       ; A = 01000000 Carry = 0
RR  A       ; A = 00100000 Carry = 0
AND A,0xE0  ; A = 00100000 Carry = 0
```

Here, the AND has no effect.  But, suppose we multiplied by something that would cause overflow, such as 17 * 32:

```
Start       ; A = 00010001 Carry = 0
RR  A       ; A = 00001000 Carry = 1
RR  A       ; A = 10000100 Carry = 0
RR  A       ; A = 01000010 Carry = 0
RR  A       ; A = 00100001 Carry = 1
AND A,0xE0  ; A = 00100000 Carry = 0
```

Without the and, we'd have gotten 17 * 32 = 33, rather than the correct answer for 1 byte (`32`).  While neither of those answers are the true answer (544), `32` is the correct value for the first byte of it.

Answer (score 3):

I tested it using [CPCtelera](http://lronaldo.github.io/cpctelera/) (which includes SDCC 3.4.3) and result seems correct. I used this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char one() { return 1; }

void main() {
   unsigned char r;
   r = one() * 32; 
   printf("1 * 32 = %d\n\r", r);
   while (1);
}
```

And this was the generated code (only relevant part of the code):

```
_main::
;src/main.c:28: r = one() * 32;
call    _one
ld  a,l
rrca
rrca
rrca
and a,#0xE0
```

It seems clear to me that you are right, and the version of SDCC you have is incorrectly using `rr` instead of `rrca`.

Finally, this is the output of the program, on WinAPE Amstrad CPC emulator:

[image: Output on WinAPE 2.0. Alpha 18]

Comment: The version of SDCC used in GBDK is *ancient*. As in '90s.